# powershell select-string columns

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a bunch of IIS logs and powershell 2.0.

Currently i'm using the following command to find some info out about them (where 'crossdomain' occurs in them):

```
dir -r -i *.log | select-string "crossdomain" | Select-Object | export-csv test.csv
```

This then gives me some data like so:

```
TRUE    1132740 2011-06-09 11:13:49 W3SVC322653822 myserver-WEB1 1.1.1.1 GET /crossdomain.xml - 80 - 1.1.1.1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+Trident/4.0;+GTB6.5;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+Media+Center+PC+5.0;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618) WT_FPC=id=82.40.25.58-3980883472.30062468:lv=1307614413232:ss=1307614405277;+__utma=151217894.932228880.1307618019.1307618019.1307618019.1;+__utmz=151217894.1307618019.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);+myserverVISITOR=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;+myserverGFSurvey=1;+ebNewBandWidth_.myserver.co.uk=251%3A1303383702897;+__utmb=151217894.1.10.1307618019;+__utmc=151217894 - myserver.co.uk 200 0 0 601 1506 0   W3SVC322653822_ex110609.log.log E:\w3\W3SVC322653822_ex110609.log.log   crossdomain     System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]
```

which is fine and dandy, but not dandy enough.

What I really want to do is get an export of the 7th column from the end where crossdomain occurs in the file.  So this part in here:

```
**myserver.co.uk** 200 0 0 601 1506 0
```

(the myserver.co.uk)

any tips on this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Mjolinors' answer, but I'd try to keep the regexp as simple as possible. And since you've already selected lines with the word "crossdomain" you don't have to search for just that:

```
Get-Content test.csv  | Foreach-Object
{
   if ($_ -match '(\w+\.\w+\.\w+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+)')
   {
       $matches[1]
   }
}
```

You won't get any 'Unexpected token' error, but you might have to tweak the regexp to get the result you want (I'm presuming you're looking for a three-dot domain and six numbers after it).

And always use '' for strings when you don't need variable extrapolation. it's much safer.

Answer (score 1):

```
get-content  test.csv |
 foreach -object {
 $_ -match ".+\s([a-z\.]+)\s[\s\d]+\S+\s\S+\s+crossdomain\s+\S+$" > $nul
 $matches[1]
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying this but i'm getting a Unexpected token 'matches' in expression or statement

Comment: I can't duplicate that errors.  It worked fine for me with the test data that was posted.  Are you sure got the script copied/pasted correctly?